# How to present a view controller that is in the "main" storyboard from a view controller that isn't in the storyboard but is created programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am creating a polling app with several different polls to select from. To do this I created a View Controller in the storyboard called PollSelectorTableViewController. It looks like this:

[image]

It is a static table cell and when I press it, it transitions to SubPollsTableViewController. This however, is not part of the storyboard.

This is the code within the SubPollsTableViewController (excluding where I am having the problem) and it works perfectly:

```
import UIKit

class SubPollsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var polls:[String]
static var pollSelectOptions:[String] = [""]

let blueColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
let redColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 41.0/255.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

init(setPolls:[String]){
    self.polls = setPolls
    print(self.polls)
    super.init(style: .plain)
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return polls.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print(indexPath)
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.textLabel?.text = polls[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.font = cell.textLabel?.font.withSize(50.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == (polls.count - 1)){
        cell.textLabel?.text = polls[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = redColor
        cell.textLabel?.font = cell.textLabel?.font.withSize(25.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = polls[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = blueColor
        cell.textLabel?.font = cell.textLabel?.font.withSize(21.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    }
    return cell
}
```

*note that the code is not finished

From here I try to make it that when a cell is clicked on, it changes to a View Controller (named PollViewController) that I defined in the storyboard. Here is an image of the View Controller:

[image: Poll View Controller]

What I did to try and get it to work is:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print (indexPath)
    if(polls[indexPath.row] == "Background Checks"){
        print("Background Checks Accessed")
        SubPollsTableViewController.pollSelectOptions = ["Increase Drastically","Increase Slightly","Stay the Same","Decrease Slightly","Decrease Drastically"]
        actioncall()
    }
    }

    func actioncall() {

    if let PVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PollViewController") as? PollViewController {
        PVC.selectOptions = SubPollsTableViewController.pollSelectOptions
        self.present(PVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    }
```

This should cause the SubPollsTableViewController to change to the PollViewController, but instead my exception breakpoint stops it at

```
    self.present(PVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Letting it run anyway brings up "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix this problem so that they switch? The text in the PollViewController is just placeholder text by the way. I got the code based off of several different sources within and outside Stack Exchange but it still isn't working.

Comment: Your code to show PollViewController is correct. I think that it’s something with your PollViewController, are your outlets correctly connected?

Comment: How can I connect outlets if there is no SubPollsTableViewController in the storyboard to connect from? I can't even check if they are connected in the first place.

Comment: Also, it did work once but not anytime after that. I hadn't changed anything so I don't know why it suddenly started giving me this error.

Comment: I’m referring to PollViewController.

Comment: You were right, there were some messed up connections.

Comment: This was such a simple fix that I couldn't figure out - that's countless hours wasted.

Comment: It happens ;) I will put it in an answer so you can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to show the PollViewController is correct, this types of exceptions are related with outlets connection so you can verify if your outlets are connected correctly in your PollViewController.